# custom field with total count of Facebook likes, comments and shares

Tags: custom-field, facebook

i want to make custom filed that contains facebook like count for the post url
to get the likes i used this code

```
function fb_count(){
$link = get_permalink($post->ID);
$content = file_get_contents("http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=".$link);
$element = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
$shareCount = $element->link_stat->total_count;
return $shareCount;}
```

which i don't know how to store the Facebook data in custom filed 
i tried this code but it dos not work

```
<?php $like_key = 'likes_count';
     $link = get_permalink($id);
$content = file_get_contents("http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?   method=links.getStats&urls=".$link);
$element = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
$shareCount = $element->link_stat->total_count;
 $key1_values = get_post_custom_values($like_key, $id);
    foreach ( $key1_values as $value )
     update_post_meta($id,$like_key,$shareCount, $value); ?>
```

i wanna know i what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done it, here is the complete code:

```
function insert_facebook_likes_custom_field($post_ID) {
    global $wpdb;
    if (!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
        add_post_meta($post_ID, 'likes_count', '0', true);
    }
}
add_action('publish_page', 'insert_facebook_likes_custom_field');
add_action('publish_post', 'insert_facebook_likes_custom_field');

function update_facebook_likes($content = '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $permalink = get_permalink();
    $idpost = $wp_query->post->ID;
    $data = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?id='.$permalink);
    $json = $data;
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    $like_no = $obj->{'shares'};
    $meta_values = get_post_meta($idpost, 'likes_count', true);
    if ($like_no == null) {
        $like_no = 0;
    }
    update_post_meta($idpost, 'likes_count', $like_no, false);
    return $content;
}
add_action('the_content', 'update_facebook_likes');
```

Just copy/paste this code into functions.php. The data will store in a custom field called likes_count. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For display number of Facebook fans in full text, i used this part of code :

```
$page_id = "YOUR PAGE-ID";
$xml = @simplexml_load_file("http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=facebook.fql.query&query=SELECT%20fan_count%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id=".$page_id."") or die ("a lot");
$fans = $xml->page->fan_count;
echo $fans;
```

"YOUR PAGE-ID" -> the ID of Facebook page. I hope to be useful.

Comment: You could also cache the Number, so you improve the performance because not connecting to facebook every time.

Answer (score 0):

See [Getting Facebook Likes, Shares and Comment Counts Using PHP Function](http://www.upgradedtutorials.info/php/getting-facebook-likes-shares-and-comment-counts-using-php-function/).
Its a newer version where you can get the facebook likes, comment, and share counts using facebook FQL and get it via json and display it as a text. you can manipulate the view and design it in a way you want. Its so handy, simpler Code, and soo useful

Comment: Please post an example of the code one might use