# WP Query - Is this correct?

Tags: custom-field, query-posts, meta-query, order

Trying to debug, getting headache so I want to ensure that I have placed the query args in the correct place. I want to sort/order all my posts based on "myvalue".

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
    /* Start the Loop */
    $args = array(
        'meta_key' => 'myvalue',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC' 
    );
    query_posts( $args );
    /* End Condition */
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;
endif;
```

**EDIT:** Updated the code:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_value_num' => 'likes_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
);
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
while ($posts->have_posts()): $posts->the_post();
endwhile;
```

I'm using this piece of code to retrieve the meta value 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/66955

Comment: ___Don't use `query_posts`___. What doesn't work exactly? What do you expect to happen that doesn't?

Comment: What am I supposed to replace it with? And it doesn't change anything. So I'm trying to pin down the problem whether it's the meta key's fault or the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing but based on your choice of placeholder names in the code above...

```
$args = array(
  'meta_key' => 'myvalue',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => 'DESC' 
);
```

... your `meta_key` argument is wrong. That is the meta *key* not the meta value as your naming convention suggests.

> meta_key (string) - Custom field key.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Replace `query_posts` with a new `WP_Query` object or use a filter on `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query. This site is full of examples for both. Even the Codex tells you not to use this function:

> Note: This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

If that doesn't help then you are going to have to provide more information, but my guess would be that your `meta_value` isn't numeric but has other things as well-- punctuation, letters, something.

Based on the updated code, I am pretty sure that what you want is thsi:

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'paged' => $paged,
  'meta_key' => 'likes_count',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
);
```

Comment: I have updated the code, is it correct now?

Comment: @TonyFire : see the update

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_key' => 'myvalue',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
);

$posts = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<?php while($posts->have_posts()): $posts->the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This should work, make sure you're using the correct meta_key.